# javascript code behind values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have the following JS code which shows/hides buttons (had to be done this way, and please don't say do it another way).

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
                document.getElementById("ltInstructions").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("btnToExcel").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
                    if(<%=resultsCount %> > 0)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("ltInstructions").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("btnToExcel").style.visibility = "visible";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<br><b><center><font size=20>No results found, please try again.</b></font></center>";
                    }
                }
```

The problem is `<%=resultsCount %>` which gets initialized to 0 in the code behind and then later updated in Timer_Tick method. The Js above always picks it up as 0.

How to make the JS pick it up as the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asp:hiddenfield instead and change its value in Timer_Tick, You will get updated value for it.

**In HTML**

```
 <asp:HiddenField id="resultsCount" runat="server" Value="String" />
```

**In Javascript**

```
resultsCount = document.getElementById('<%= resultsCount.ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: Thank you. That has fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the source of the webpage in your browser. You have to write the timer in JavaScript, because `<%=resultsCount %>` is evaluated **once only** and therefore, all the client sees is

```
 if (0 > 0) {
   ...
 }
```

You can implement a timer in JavaScript using the `setInterval` and `clearInterval` methods. Define a function `update()` that should be called whenever something needs to be updated and then do

```
var updateInterval

function update() {
  if(condition) {
    /* update stuff */
  } else {
    /* no more updates needed */
    clearInterval(updateInterval) /* stop updating */
  }
}

updateInterval = setInterval(update, 1000) /* call update() every 1000 ms, that is every second */
```

Comment: yes that is correct I do get 0 > 0. How to perform the timer in JS?